# syslog const char* to string

Tags: c++, string, pointers, constants

```
   catch (exception e) { syslog (LOG_ERR, "exception: " + e.what());    }
```

Here is what im trying to do, And it aint working, ive tried using this

```
string ctos(const char& c){

    stringstream s;
    s << c;

    return s.str();
}
```

But still lost

Any help would be apreciated Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a `const char*` (as per your question) or `const char` (passed by reference, as per your code) to a `string`? Your usage is unclear.

Comment: Although it is not relevant to the question, I recommend using `const exception& e` in `catch` because otherwise your exception object will be truncated to `exception`.

Comment: Security note: As a general rule, only use string literals in printf or syslog type format strings. If it is a variable, pass it as a parameter. In this example what if someone did this: `throw std::runtime_error( std::string("Bad user input: ") + user_input )` and the user input contained a format attack? Your program would be toast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
catch (exception e) 
{ 
         syslog (LOG_ERR, "exception: %s" ,e.what());   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `std::string` constructor taking `const char*`, see [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/). So your logging code can be corrected as follows:

```
catch (const exception& e) {
    syslog (LOG_ERR, (std::string("exception: ") + e.what()).c_str());
}
```

Comment: @Angel.King.47: Apparently syslog takes `const char*` as a second argument so add the call to `c_str()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [`syslog(3)`](http://resin.csoft.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=8&topic=syslog) then it is defined as:

```
void syslog(int priority, const char *message, ...);
```

Either you want to use `printf`-like functionality of `syslog`:

```
catch (const std::exception& e) 
{ 
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "exception: %s", e.what());
}
```

Or you can convert the `std::string` to `const char*`, using the `std::string::c_str` member function:

```
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::string message = std::string("exception: ") + e.what();
    syslog(LOG_ERR, message.c_str());
}
```

Another note, catch by const-reference, else it is a good chance that the actual thrown exception object gets [sliced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).